# How To Get Jspinner max value from input field attribute

Tags: jquery, spinner, jspinner, jquery-ui-spinner

Using While Loop i'm generating below given jsippner i want put max value of each Spinner Input to number which is given in previous "Available Room" column... I have used below given Jquery to add event to each input box... Plase help me achieve this

Jquery:-

```
$('.spinner3').spinner({
    value:0, 
    min: 0,
    max: 10
});
```

HTML :-

```
<div class="spinner3"><div class="input-group" style="width:150px;"><input type="text" class="spinner-input form-control" maxlength="'.$ava_rm.'" readonly><div class="spinner-buttons input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default spinner-up" style="background-color:#56b556"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default spinner-down" style="background-color: #FF9800;"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button></div></div></div>
```

[image: Jspinner Image]

Comment: You need to set the max value of your spinner ? **$( ".selector" ).spinner( "option", "max", 50 );**

Comment: @Kashkain I Guess i was unable explain my issue wisely... Now in above example i want to set input value to max of each Spinner according to value given in available rooms column... i'm creating this spinner using while this input field <input type="text" class="spinner-input form-control" maxlength="'.$ava_rm.'" readonly> with attribute "maxlength" contain that max value which needed to set for each spinner field

Comment: I don't think you can attach a JQuery UI spinner to a div...